# Simple data binding is not interpolating the value

Tags: angularjs

I was starting to work on a simple project and started out with simple one way binding to make sure, the controller is bound so that view can see the variables.
 
Initially I started out with  separate javascript file containing the controller and it was not working so I moved it to the inline script thinking some how angular was not loading the controller script. Either way, it was is not working. 
Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mtKHBVepPTEXfWGIUjfe?p=preview)
Thanks

Comment: It does the job, when you use an element other then the body tag.

Comment: funny, did not see I was adding ng-app in the head, kept thinking it was in html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the `ng-app` directive placed on the `<head>` element which means that it was also this element (plus its children) being managed by AngularJS.

Move the `ng-app` to the `<html>` or `<body>` element and your application will work:
http://plnkr.co/edit/O1W8HVfeyXS6zl61Qb8I?p=preview